# How to suppress popping-up of alt tooltip for an AREA tag?

Tags: html, title, alt-attribute

I am using an image map which contains a lot of `<area>` tags. I have `alt` attributes for each of the area which gets popped up as a tooltip in IE. Can we suppress this behavior? I tried using empty `title` attribute but it did not work.

*Edit:* I need the alt attribute for other screen readers. So i cannot just make it empty ir remove it. I just want to supress its popping up behavior in IE.
am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the browser is IE using `navigator.appName` etc. (unreliable).

If it is IE, remove all `alt` attributes of the `<area>` tags (not tested):

```
var area_tags = document.getElementsByTagName("area");
for (var i = area_tags.length-1; i >= 0; -- i)
  area_tags[i].removeAttribute("alt");
```

---

Or just don't care.

Comment: :) I guess i will go with 'Just dont care option'. Also, i can put another function to refill the alt onmouseout apart from removing it using onmouseover. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

.......

```
<area onmouseover="this.alt = '';">
```

I know Javascript shouldn't be inline, but you can convert it into function easily.

**Update: With JQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $('area').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).attr('alt', '');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use empty alt attributes

```
<area alt="" />
```

See **[Blank alt attributes](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2004/12/08/blank-alt-attributes/)**

Answer (score -1):

Use a style like `area.alt {display: none;}` to suppress the alt.